# How to track utm_source in Google Analytics using gtag?

Tags: javascript, analytics

I'm having difficulties tracking utm_source, utm_medium with gtag. I have an SPA in AngularJS, so all the page views are fired dynamically. I've been looking for solutions to track these values from gtag, but the only hint I found is this:

```js
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async="async" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('set', 'page_title', 'FBIA: '+ia_document.title);
  gtag('set', 'campaignSource', 'Facebook');
  gtag('set', 'campaignMedium', 'Social Instant Article');

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
</script>
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/danielmcclure/559c2fe2433035f72d80fe45755af7bf

Unfortunately this is not working for me, neither for others:

https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Code/How-can-you-set-Campaign-Source-Medium-etc-with-custom-values/td-p/1307828

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 12):

Finally I managed to find this out, by beautifying the gtag.js code and searching for "campaignSource". It seems the current method is:

```js
gtag('config', 'YOUR_TRACKING_ID', {
  ...some_other_configs,
  campaign: {
    source: 'Some source', // utm_source
    medium: 'Some medium' // utm medium
  }
});
```

It's a shame that there isn't a comprehensive documentation of gtag. But at least I wasn't forced to switch back to ga...

Comment: Don't forget to set both the source and medium. Doesn't seems to work otherwise!

Comment: How did you manage to find these? I read all available docs and didn't find it anywhere.

Comment: @Gherman I've been beautifying Analytic's obfuscated/minified source code, then I did some searches. Reading the JS source it was pretty clear how these parameters were meant to be used. It's strange they forgot to mention these things in their documentation...

Comment: Is this still working today? In my case it sends a "campaign" field with the "object" value instead of the two values separately

Answer (score 8):

I also needed utm_campaign and utm_content as well.  Anything you don't set seems to get wiped out, so I also searched code and found I could do this:  (note the ga prefixed variables are things I determined in earlier JavaScript

```js
gtag('config', 'YOUR_TRACKING_ID', {
    campaign: {
        medium: gaMedium,
        source: gaSource,
        name: gaCampaign,
        content: gaContent
    }
});
```