# GA4 - Correct way to send UTM campaign data using Measurement protocol?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol, utm

Im missing something with the `UTM` information using GA4's Measurement protocol.

With the old Universal Analytics, this data only needed to be set through the url (`utm_source=sourceValue&utm_medium=mediumValue&utm_campaign=campaignValue`), and will be [stored in the `user_id` session automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295802/ga-how-to-measure-source-medium-and-campaign-using-measurement-protocol-auct), so when i was using Mesurement protocol calls from my backend i only needed to give the `user_id` and the `UTM` parameters will populate automatically.

But with GA4 I don't find any way to do my backend calls with this `UTM` data also sending `client_id` and `user_id` parameters.

I found ways to set `UTM` parameters [using `gtag`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231721/how-to-track-utm-source-in-google-analytics-using-gtag) but it doesen't work the same way using Measurement protocol... I also tried doing the call [using get parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) `https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?cn=campaignValue&cs=campaignSource&cm=campaignMedium&measurement_id=${measurement_id}&api_secret=${api_secret}` and post parameters it works fine with the params (`cs` `cn` `cm`), but im unable to find the campaign information in GA4 dashboards.

Anyone struggling with this?

Comment: measurement protocol for ga4 is limited they are still working on it

Comment: Thanks A LOT for answering i was almost blind here... do you have any official source about this, do google have any plans for the near future?

Comment: I know they are still working on it but I haven't been told exactly what they are doing.   I think we need to wait and see what happens in the next six months.    I'm also under NDA so even if I did know more I couldn't say.    ‍♀️  let me just send you question off to them though

Comment: You need to use the `campaign_details` event to send campaign data to GA4, which can then be linked to the user with `client_id` and/or `user_id`. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference/events#campaign_details

Comment: @SimoAhava Already fired an event `campaign_details`... But it don't appear in the debug view... But with a debug call `/debug/mp/` it doesn't show any validation messages... so i must put this event inside the `events` array or it must be executed before another MP call? Any example to send this as a `purchase` as an answer will be super helpful!

Comment: Also, @SimoAhava I've test this yesterday, in the same event and with different events, but GA4 the UTM information seems to not reach google analytics... Maybe I'm doing something wrong or Google doesn't support the event `campaign_details` as we expect?

Comment: @GBS the team is looking into it.  campaign_details  should be the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Using `campaign_details` event to send campaign params:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference/events#campaign_details.

Important: `session_id` must also be added to. It can be acquired from a GA cookie variable: `_ga_<GA measurement_id>`, the first large number.
For example, GS1.1.**1704773506**.16.1.1704777354.0.0.0 // 1704773506 is what you need.

This API function can extract it:

```
gtag('get', '<Measurement ID>', 'session_id', (id) => {})
```

Example request body:

```
{
   "client_id": "123456.7654321",
   "events": [
     {
        "name": "campaign_details",
        "params": {
          "campaign_id": "google_1234",
          "campaign": "Summer_fun",
          "source": "google",
          "medium": "cpc",
          "term": "summer+travel",
          "content": "logolink",
          "session_id": 1231313, // must be integer value
          "engagement_time_msec": "100"
        }
     },
     {
      "name": "purchase",
      "params": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "transaction_id": "T_12345",
        "value": 12.21,
        "coupon": "SUMMER_FUN",
        "shipping": 3.33,
        "tax": 1.11,
        "session_id": 1231313,
        "items": [
          {
            ...
          }
        ]
      }
   ]
  }
```

This video has more information about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_eoeU2qUn0